# Как передать изображения/изображение InputStream/OutputStream и отобразить в imageView

Tags: java, android, java-output-stream

Есть приложение, которое передаёт через WiFi direct строку в виде байтов. Как мне реализовать передачу файлов? Добавил `urisList` - список Uri файлов, получилось вытянуть `File` в `ByteArray`. И передать на устройство.
Вопросы:

1. Как произвести вывод изображения в imageView? В `Handler` если выводить в imageView:

```
val readBuff = msg.obj as ByteArray
val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(readBuff, 0, readBuff.size)
Glide
  .with(this)
  .load(bitmap)
  .into(this.imageView!!)
```

Изображение не устанавливается, байты по логам приходят, те же, что и были отправлены, но `Log.e("RESULT", readBuff.toString())` повторяются с байтами около 20-30 раз (как я понял, оправляются 20-30 раз).
2. Как передать несколько файлов?

```
private var buttonOnOff: Button? = null
private var buttonSend: Button? = null
private var textViewRead: TextView? = null
var connectionStatus: TextView? = null
private var writeMsg: EditText? = null
private var wifiManager: WifiManager? = null
private var mManager: WifiP2pManager? = null
private var mChannel: WifiP2pManager.Channel? = null
private var mReceiver: BroadcastReceiver? = null
private var mIntentFilter: IntentFilter? = null
private var peers: MutableList<WifiP2pDevice> = ArrayList()
private var deviceNameArray: Array<String?> = arrayOf()
private var deviceArray: Array<WifiP2pDevice?> = arrayOf()
private var serverClass: ServerClass? = null
private var clientClass: ClientClass? = null
private var sendReceive: SendReceive? = null
private var urisList = mutableListOf<Uri?>()

var handler: Handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) { msg ->
    when (msg.what) {
        MESSAGE_READ -> {
                val readBuff = msg.obj as ByteArray
                val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(readBuff, 0, readBuff.size)
                Glide
                    .with(this)
                    .load(bitmap)
                    .into(this.imageView!!)
        }
    }
    true
}

buttonSend!!.setOnClickListener {
    val path = getPath(urisList[0]!!)
    val file = File(path)
    if (file.exists()) {
        sendReceive?.write(file.readBytes())
    }
}

inner class SendReceive(private val socket: Socket?) : Thread() {
    private var inputStream: InputStream? = null
    private var outputStream: OutputStream? = null
    override fun run() {
        val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
        var bytes: Int
        while (socket != null) {
            try {
                bytes = inputStream!!.read(buffer)
                if (bytes > 0) {
                    handler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget()
                }
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }

    fun write(bytes: ByteArray?) {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            try {
                outputStream!!.write(bytes)
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }

    init {
        try {
            inputStream = socket!!.getInputStream()
            outputStream = socket.getOutputStream()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы отдаёте хандлеру куски размером по 1024 байта. Соберите их в один массив  - получите изображение.

Comment: @woesss т.е. не указывать размер в том же блоке кода?

Comment: А вообще-то я не вижу где у вас приём/передача конкретно изображения - покажите актуальный код вашей попытки.

Comment: @woesss как собрать в массив? Можете примером помочь? Добавил фрагменты кода.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1264737/15923106 - вот так, например.